# Errors during rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have been trying to upgrade my app from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3. I got the rails s to work with no errors but nothing will come up because I have not migrated the db. There has been numerous errors I have fixed trying to run rake db:migrate but I cannot get past this...

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- config/environment

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my config environment is

```
#Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
AppName::Application.initialize!
```

with trace

```
    rake aborted!
    no such file to load -- config/environment
   /Users/Kyle/Desktop/Rails_Projects/unitedaction3/lib/tasks/account.rake:2:in `require'
   /Users/Kyle/Desktop/Rails_Projects/unitedaction3/lib/tasks/account.rake:2:in `<top     (required)>'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `block in     load_tasks'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `each'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load_tasks'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:141:in   `load_tasks'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
   /Users/Kyle/Desktop/Rails_Projects/unitedaction3/Rakefile:9:in `<top (required)>'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in   load_rakefile'
  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
    /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
   /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run it with `--trace` and post the result here, might help.

Comment: What's in `/lib/tasks/account.rake`? It looks like *maybe* you need to change the reference to `environment.rb` in that file to be a relative path (i.e. `../../config/environment.rb`. This is just a guess so I won't post it as an answer yet.

Comment: Are you trying to manually `require` `config/environment.rb` or are you passing `:environment` in the task definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have seen this but there is a rails plugin that provides rake tasks to help with this upgrade: https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade

It gives you:

```
rake rails:upgrade:check
rake rails:upgrade:configuration
```

But I think what you will need to end up doing is generate a new empty rails 3 app and copy the generated `config/environment` file into your app.